# Connection to database (SQLSRV_Connect())

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a database on a MSSQL Server. There are 2 users. 
The first one is a local db user. The second one is a windows user. Both have the same permission.

If I try to connect the db with my local user, it works!

```
class db {

static $serverName = "SERVERNAME"; 
static $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBName", "UID"=>"local_user", "PWD"=>"password_local");
static $conn;

function connectToDB(){

    global $serverName,$connectionInfo,$conn;

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect(self::$serverName , self::$connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         //echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection to Database could not be established, please contact your admin!<br />";
         //die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

...but when I try to connect the database with my windows user, I've got an error. I only changed the user name to DOMAIN\win_user and the pw to the windows pw.

Here is the error message:

```
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\win_user'.
SQLSTATE: 28000
code: 18456
```

Comment: Did you add it to the Users? Rules of the database?

Comment: And have you tried logging directly to MSSQL with that windows account? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, the User is added with the same permission db_owner. I can login with my windows user in mssql management server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't mapped user to database.
Go to Security->User Account->Right click to user and then Property. Go to User Mapping, select DB and below click to "db_owner" role

Comment: Yes, the permissions are the same.

Comment: Use this credential: `$serverName = "(local)";  
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBName", NULL, NULL);`

Comment: SQLSTATE: IMSSP
code: -1
message: Invalid option (null) was passed to sqlsrv_connect.

Comment: @OliZ. test without 2nd e 3rd parameters but only with dbname